# REGEX validating twitter handler

Tags: php, regex

i found this function that validates the length of twitter account.

Your username can contain up to 15 characters.

```
function validate_username($username)
{
    return preg_match('/^[A-Za-z0-9_]{1,15}$/', $username);
}
```

How can I change this rule to make @ symbol optional in the beginning of the string !

Samples of valid inputs

abcdabcdabcdabc

@abcdabcdabcdabc

Comment: Simple. Just THINK. That's the keyword to learn. At least give it a try.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `?` can be used to to make the previous character optional:

```
preg_match('/^@?[A-Za-z0-9_]{1,15}$/', $username);
```

Equivalently:

```
preg_match('/^@{0,1}[A-Za-z0-9_]{1,15}$/', $username);
```

Comment: Thanks
this rule returns true for strings shorter than 15 chars
var rule=/^@{0,1}[A-Za-z0-9_]{1,15}$/;
             return rule.test(username);